# How to make Hand drawn pencil circle using pure CSS?

Tags: html, css, pure-css

Actually, I am looking for a hand-drawn pencil circle hover effect using pure CSS without using SVG. Like [this](https://codemyui.com/hand-drawn-pencil-circle-hover/) one on CodeMyUi. But this was achieved using an SVG I want to create it using only pure CSS. Please if anybody knows this answer me.

Comment: no way with pure CSS. Either the mentioned SVG or a PNG as background. Clip-path could be used but would be super close to a SVG and very hacky to beginn with. With that efford you coul use a svg in the first palce.

Comment: Please can you help me out with this we can use an image as a background but not SVG this is requirement?Please if you can do this let me know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could try something like this?

```css
.circle-on-hover {
  padding: 16px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 16px;
}

.circle-on-hover:hover:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 100px 50px 150px;
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-on-hover">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

You could fiddle with the border-radius and rotation to change the effect, and maybe add `:before` to get the cross-over in the top right?

Hope this points you in the right direction - please let me know :-)

Comment: Yeah Kate this is an amazing try but my client wants exactly the same thing. Is it possible with the pure CSS if not please tell me another way other than SVG may be an image or something like this but please help me out.

Comment: Can we achieve this task using background image. If we can please let me know how to do this?

Comment: The requirement is changed i only want a hand drawn circle like i showed not hover effect just a hand-drawn circle.

Comment: Background image is probably the best way, in that case.

Comment: Yes i did it. Thanks kate

Comment: Great! Could you please mark my answer as accepted? Thanks in advance